Keep some parts different between two git branches
Is it possible to have git track some directory, which is different between two branches, without attempting to merge onto each other branch?
Like we have two branches with the following files:
master:
     src/main.c
     config/main.cfg

testing:
     src/main.c
     config/test.cfg

and I expect every change to main.c would merge on pull. Also both branches would track changes to their respective files in config/, but not showing any changes of the other branch on pull.

As long as you never merge testing into master or vice versa, the two branches can stay diverged. That probably implies you want a third branch that manages changes that should be merged into both testing and master, at which point you might discover that the names aren't quite right.

There's no reason you can't have main.cfg and test.cfg together in the same branch, and any differences between the two main.c files should probably be refactored so that there is no difference between the two branches. Whether your program reads one config file or the other is best left to how you deploy the code, not something for Git to manage.

@chepner That second comment should be an answer. It's the clearest most convincing statement of the case that I've ever seen. This "problem" comes up again and again and it would be nice to have a solid locus to refer people to.

Ah i see.. however, that won't work if the config would be named config.cfg in both branches... which may also happen. It is a more general question, if differences between branches can be automatically ignored on merging but still diffed on the branches itself. Like .gitignore for merging only.
